# How to align bibliography to the left

Tags: bibliographies, lyx, align, natbib, lyx-layouts

I am using a custom bibliography style I created with makebst. For some reason, the references are not aligned to the left, only the first line is aligned to the left and the rest seems to be indented. How can I fix that. I use the package natbib and author-cite type of citations.

[image: Screenshot of bibliography layout in LyX]

This is the preamble of my document

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,french]{article}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\pagestyle{headings}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
\pdfpageheight\paperheight
\pdfpagewidth\paperwidth

\newcommand{\noun}[1]{\textsc{#1}}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\addto\extrasfrench{%
   \providecommand{\og}{\leavevmode\flqq~}%
   \providecommand{\fg}{\ifdim\lastskip>\z@\unskip\fi~\frqq}%
}

\begin{document}
```

It shows the bibliography the same way in LyX and TeXmaker. I uploaded the bst file as well : http://hu.lk/d5pn8ebdwjy8 How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given that you use `natbib`, the indentation of the lines after the first one is controlled by the length `\bibhang`. You can change it by using

```
\setlength{\bibhang}{0pt}
```