# Aligning bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, horizontal-alignment

I am trying to align my bibliography, at the moment it is looking like this:

[image: my bib]

The red line indicates the problem: For multi-line bibliography entries, the first line is not aligned with all others. I would like to have all lines starting at the green line.

This picture has been created with the following code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,oneside]{scrbook}
\begin{document}

some random text with one citation to deepmind \cite{GoogleAtari} and one to some other \cite{ReinforcementReview} and another \cite{erven2014experimental}.

\bibliographystyle{xxxunsrt}
\bibliography{refs}

\end{document}
```

and the refs.bib looks as follows:

```
@article{GoogleAtari,
  title={Human-level control through deep reinforcement learning},
  author={Volodymyr Mnih and Koray Kavukcuoglu and David Silver and Andrei A. Rusu and Joel Veness and Marc G. Bellemare and Alex Graves and Martin Riedmiller and Andreas K. Fidjeland and Georg Ostrovski and Stig Petersen and Charles Beattie and Amir Sadik and Ioannis Antonoglou and Helen King and Dharshan Kumaran and Daan Wierstra and Shane Legg and Demis Hassabis},
  journal={Nature},
  volume={518},
  number={7540},
  pages={529--533},
  year={2015},
  publisher={Nature Publishing Group}
}


@article{ReinforcementReview,
  title={Reinforcement learning improves behaviour from evaluative feedback},
  author={Littman, Michael L},
  journal={Nature},
  volume={521},
  number={7553},
  pages={445--451},
  year={2015},
  publisher={Nature Publishing Group}
}

@article{erven2014experimental,
  title={Experimental three-photon quantum nonlocality under strict locality conditions},
  author={C. Erven and E. Meyer-Scott and K. Fisher and J. Lavoie and B. L. Higgins and Z. Yan and C. J. Pugh and J.-P. Bourgoin and R. Prevedel and L. K. Shalm and L. Richards and N. Gigov and R. Laflamme and G. Weihs and T. Jennewein and K. J. Resch},
  journal={Nature photonics},
  volume={8},
  number={4},
  pages={292--296},
  year={2014},
  publisher={Nature Publishing Group}
}
```

The question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82731/how-to-align-bibliography-to-the-left) sounded similar, however it didn't solve my problem (even if i add `natbib`. I'm using MikTeX 2.9, and `xxxunsrt.bst` is costumized (with [bib-it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203564/how-to-modify-unsrt-bst-file-to-generate-concise-and-readable-jounal-of-applie)).

I'm trying this for quite some time now, and would be very happy for every hint!

---

**Edit:**

And here is a shrinked, but still very large `xxxunsrt.bst` file

```
ENTRY
  { 
    author
    booktitle
    journal
    pages
    publisher
    title
    url
    volume
    year
  }
  {}
  { label }
INTEGERS { output.state before.all mid.sentence after.sentence after.block }
FUNCTION {init.state.consts}
{ #0 'before.all :=
  #1 'mid.sentence :=
  #2 'after.sentence :=
  #3 'after.block :=
}
STRINGS { s t}
FUNCTION {output.nonnull}
{ 's :=
  output.state mid.sentence =
    { ", " * write$ }
    { output.state after.block = 
        { add.period$ write$
          newline$
          "\newblock " write$
        }
        { output.state before.all =
            'write$
            { add.period$ " " * write$ }
          if$
        }
      if$
      mid.sentence 'output.state :=
    }
  if$
  s
}
FUNCTION {output.nonnull.nostate}
{ 's :=
  output.state after.block =
    { add.period$ write$
      newline$
      "\newblock " write$
    }
    'write$
  if$
  s
}
FUNCTION {output}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    'pop$
    'output.nonnull
  if$
}
FUNCTION {output.check}
{ 't :=
  duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "empty " t * " in " * cite$ * warning$ }
    'output.nonnull
  if$
}
INTEGERS { nameptr namesleft numnames posothers showetal}

FUNCTION {output.bibitem}
{ newline$
  "\bibitem{" write$
  cite$ write$
  "}" write$
  newline$
  ""
  before.all 'output.state :=
}
FUNCTION {bibinfo.check}
{ swap$
  duplicate$ missing$
    {
      pop$ pop$
      ""
    }
    { duplicate$ empty$
        {
           swap$ pop$
        }
        { swap$
          pop$
        }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {fin.entry}
{ add.period$
  write$
  newline$
}
FUNCTION {new.block}
{ output.state before.all =
    'skip$
    { after.block 'output.state := }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {new.sentence}
{ output.state after.block =
    'skip$
    { output.state before.all =
        'skip$
        { after.sentence 'output.state := }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {add.blank}
{  " " * before.all 'output.state :=
}
FUNCTION {add.colon}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    'skip$
    { ":" * add.blank }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {not}
{   { #0 }
    { #1 }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {and}
{   'skip$
    { pop$ #0 }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {or}
{   { pop$ #1 }
    'skip$
  if$
}
FUNCTION {field.or.null}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    'skip$
  if$
}
FUNCTION {bolden}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    { "\textbf{" swap$ * "}" * }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {italize}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    { "\textit{" swap$ * "}" * }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {scaps}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    { "\textsc{" swap$ * "}" * }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {anglequote}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    { "<<" swap$ * ">>" * }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {singlequote}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    { "'{}" swap$ * "'{}" * }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {doublequote}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    { "``{}" swap$ * "''{}" * }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.names.author}
{
  's :=

  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=

  numnames 'namesleft :=
  #0 'posothers :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr "{f{.}.}{ ll}" format.name$ 't :=
      t "others" =
         { nameptr 'posothers := }
         'skip$
       if$
       nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
       namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$

  #0 'showetal :=

  numnames #50 >
    { #50 'numnames :=
      #1 'showetal :=
    }
    { numnames #50 =
        { posothers #0 >
          { #1 'showetal :=
            #50 'numnames :=
          }
          'skip$
         if$
         }
         { posothers #0 >
             { #1 'showetal :=
               #1 'numnames -
             }
             'skip$
           if$
         }
       if$
    }
  if$

  #1 'nameptr :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr "{f{.}.}{ ll}" format.name$ 't :=
      nameptr #1 >
        { namesleft #1 >
            { ", " * t * }
            { showetal #0 >
                { ", " * t * }
                { " and " * t * }
              if$
            }
          if$
        }
        't
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$

  showetal #0 >
    { " et~al." * }
    'skip$
  if$
}


FUNCTION {sortify}
{ purify$
  "l" change.case$
}

INTEGERS { len }


FUNCTION {chop.word}
{ 's :=
  'len :=
  s #1 len substring$ =
    { s len #1 + global.max$ substring$ }
    's
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.title.short}
{ 't :=
  "A " #2
    "An " #3
      "The " #4 t chop.word
    chop.word
  chop.word
  #1 #3 substring$
}
FUNCTION {format.article.author}
{ author
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    { format.names.author }
  if$
  "author" bibinfo.check
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
   {
   }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.article.title}
{ title
  "title" bibinfo.check
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
   {
   }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.article.journal}
{ journal
  "journal" bibinfo.check
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
   {
     italize
   }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.article.volume}
{ volume
  "volume" bibinfo.check
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
   {
     bolden
   }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.article.pages}
{ pages
  "pages" bibinfo.check
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
   {
   }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.article.year}
{ year
  "year" bibinfo.check
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
   {
   }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {article}
{ output.bibitem
  author empty$
  'skip$
    {         format.article.author
       output.nonnull.nostate
       ", "
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
   {
   }
  if$
output.nonnull.nostate    }
  if$
  new.block
  title empty$
  'skip$
    {         format.article.title
       output.nonnull.nostate
       ". "
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
   {
   }
  if$
output.nonnull.nostate    }
  if$
  new.block
  journal empty$
  'skip$
    {         format.article.journal
       output.nonnull.nostate
       " "
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
   {
   }
  if$
output.nonnull.nostate    }
  if$
  new.block
  volume empty$
  'skip$
    {         format.article.volume
       output.nonnull.nostate
       ", "
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
   {
   }
  if$
output.nonnull.nostate    }
  if$
  new.block
  pages empty$
  'skip$
    {         format.article.pages
       output.nonnull.nostate
       " "
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
   {
   }
  if$
output.nonnull.nostate    }
  if$
  new.block
  year empty$
  'skip$
    {  "("
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
   {
   }
  if$
output.nonnull.nostate       format.article.year
       output.nonnull.nostate
       ")"
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
   {
   }
  if$
output.nonnull.nostate    }
  if$
  new.block
  fin.entry
}

READ
STRINGS { longest.label }

INTEGERS { longest.label.width }

FUNCTION {initialize.longest.label}
{ "" 'longest.label :=
  #0 'longest.label.width :=
}

FUNCTION {longest.label.pass}
{ label width$ longest.label.width >
    { label 'longest.label :=
      label width$ 'longest.label.width :=
    }
    'skip$
  if$
}

EXECUTE {initialize.longest.label}

ITERATE {longest.label.pass}

FUNCTION {begin.bib}
{ preamble$ empty$
    'skip$
    { preamble$ write$ newline$ }
  if$
  "\begin{thebibliography}{"  longest.label  * "}" * write$ newline$
}
EXECUTE {begin.bib}
EXECUTE {init.state.consts}
ITERATE {call.type$}
FUNCTION {end.bib}
{ newline$
  "\end{thebibliography}" write$ newline$
}EXECUTE {end.bib}
```

and here is a [direct download link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/r32gus0fj5p4ndf/AAD9SYOoMduXo43cWYUx3Idta?dl=0) to all three files.

Comment: I cannot reproduce that with an *uncostomized* `unsrt.bst`.

Comment: By the way, there must not be a customized `unsrt.bst`.

Comment: With the legally existing version of `unsrt.bst`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dm9XH.png

Comment: @Johannes_B Oh, you are right, that is the problem :-/ Thank you for spotting this! Now I what could cause the problem. Are there some standard problems that could cause the trouble? Otherwise I will try to make a smallest-working example including the `costum-unsrt.bst`

Comment: One of the changes you did created the spacing issue. But we don't have your file.

Comment: Given that the OP does not state the necessity of strict adherence to `bibtex` and was actually initially labeled `biblatex`, wouldn't it be a good idea to suggest him to use `biblatex`'s `numeric` style instead?

Comment: A bibliographystyle, even if it is just a plain text file, is *a work of art*. You don't change the latest song of Rihanna (or somebody else) and republish it on youtube. What you do: Rename the file, get a funky beat in the backround, some synths and republish it as the *NicoDean Remix*. You would have the `unsrtNicoDean.bst`

Comment: I agree with you, i should have called differently from the beginning. I added it now (i tried to shrink it as much as possible, remove the obvious unused parts - but its still huuge, i'm sorry)

Comment: Better to upload the bib-style somewhere. We need a complete file for testing. Not even the best experts here can expand all the macros inside their head. They just run the code, look at the output and maybe look at what TeX is doing in its mouth and stomach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've broken the longest-label-mechanism while customization of `unsrt.bst`. This results in the generated `bbl`-file in:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{}
```

with empty label pattern argument. The argument is used for the indent of the items.

You can change the lines

```
INTEGERS { longest.label.width }

FUNCTION {initialize.longest.label}
{ "" 'longest.label :=
  #0 'longest.label.width :=
}

FUNCTION {longest.label.pass}
{ label width$ longest.label.width >
    { label 'longest.label :=
      label width$ 'longest.label.width :=
    }
    'skip$
  if$
}
```

in your `xxxunsrt.bst` into the original lines from `unsrt.bst`:

```
INTEGERS { number.label longest.label.width }

FUNCTION {initialize.longest.label}
{ "" 'longest.label :=
  #1 'number.label :=
  #0 'longest.label.width :=
}

FUNCTION {longest.label.pass}
{ number.label int.to.str$ 'label :=
  number.label #1 + 'number.label :=
  label width$ longest.label.width >
    { label 'longest.label :=
      label width$ 'longest.label.width :=
    }
    'skip$
  if$
}
```

After running `bibtex` again, this would result in:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{1}
```

and the alignment would be correct.

Nevertheless, I would recommend to use [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) for customization of bibliographies.

Comment: Holy cow, you are a genious! :-o How did you figure this out within 11 minutes, including writing a perfect answer? It works for me, thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

I am using **multibib** with a customized `unsrtnat.bst` and numeric citation, such as [1], [2], …, [100], … .
In my case, I didn't even have a `longest.label.pass` function.
However, I found another approach: The [multibib documentation](https://ctan.net/macros/latex/contrib/multibib/multibib.pdf) explains the `\setbiblabelwidth` command. Maybe there is a better way, but the following worked for me:

```
\setbiblabelwidth{100}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat-custom}
```

As far as I understand it, setting the width to "100" tells multibib (or whomever) to set the width to the one of the entry with the number [100]. So probably if you're facing the same problem, you can just set it to the highest number (or any number with the same amount of digits).
(I use a customized `unsrtnat.bst` which I called `unsrtnat-custom.bst`, maybe this is the problem.)