# Alignment of text in bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, bibliographystyle

My bibliography right now looks like this:
[image]

I need to have proper alignment of text. I have been trying this on my own, as well the question here [Aligning bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/368753/aligning-bibliography) does not solve my problem.

I think the problem is because I am using customised intext citations like [Gaz14-ol] or [MQT21-ol].

However, I have no choice but to do this for online resources, unless someone can suggest there is another way to do this.

The code I used:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 
    twoside, 
    12pt, 
    toc=bibliographynumbered, 
    numbers=noendperiod, 
    ngerman,
    openany, 
    fleqn]{scrbook}
\begin{document}

Example to cite \cite{Latex1} and also \cite{Latex4}.

\bibliographystyle{literature/myalphadin}
\raggedright
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{literature/literature}
\end{document}
```

my literature.bib looks like this:

```
@misc{Latex1,
    mylabel = {Uni21-ol},
    author = {Unity},
    title = {{Unity Technologies}},
    howpublished = "\url{https://unity.com/}",
    year = {Apr-2021}, 
    note = "[Online; accessed 04-Apr-2021]"
}

@misc{Latex2,
    mylabel = {ROS21-ol},
    author = {ROS},
    title = {{ROS Index}},
    howpublished = "\url{https://index.ros.org/packages/}",
    year = {Apr-2021}, 
    note = "[Online; accessed 04-Apr-2021]"
}

@INPROCEEDINGS{Latex3,
    author={R. {Codd-Downey} and P. M. {Forooshani} and A. {Speers} and H. {Wang} and M. {Jenkin}},
    booktitle={2014 IEEE International Conference on Information and Automation (ICIA)}, 
    title={From ROS to unity: Leveraging robot and virtual environment middleware for immersive teleoperation}, 
    year={2014},
    volume={},
    number={},
    pages={932-936},
    doi={10.1109/ICInfA.2014.6932785}}
@misc{Latex4,
    mylabel = {GPP$^+$20-ol},
    author = {Greene,Cameron and Platin,Jacob and Pinol,Michael and Trang,Amanda and Vij,Vidur and Gibson,Sarah},
    title = {{Robotics simulation in Unity is as easy as 1,2,3}},
    howpublished="\url{https://blogs.unity3d.com/2020/11/19/robotics-simulation-in-unity-is-as-easy-as-1-2-3/}",
    journal = {Unity Technologies Blog},
    year = {19-Nov-2020}, 
    note = "[Online; accessed 04-Apr-2021]"
}

@misc{Latex5,
    mylabel = {Gaz14-ol},
    author = {Gazebo},
    title = {{Open Source Robotics Foundation}},
    howpublished = "\url{http://gazebosim.org/}",
    year = {Mar-2014}, 
    note = "[Online; accessed 04-Apr-2021]"
}

@misc{Latex6,
    mylabel = {MQT21-ol},
    author = {MQTT},
    title = {{The Standard for IoT Messaging}},
    howpublished = "\url{https://mqtt.org/}",
    year = {Jan-2021}, 
    note = "[Online; accessed 04-Apr-2021]"
}

@INPROCEEDINGS{Latex7,  author={A. {Hussein} and F. {García} and C. {Olaverri-Monreal}},  booktitle={2018 IEEE International Conference on Vehicular Electronics and Safety (ICVES)},   title={ROS and Unity Based Framework for Intelligent Vehicles Control and Simulation},   year={2018},  volume={},  number={},  pages={1-6},  doi={10.1109/ICVES.2018.8519522}}
```

However, according to me, the problem is in the myalphadin.bst file.

I have only changed the following in the .bst file:

```
ENTRY
  { mylabel
...
}

FUNCTION {output.bibitem}
{ newline$
"\bibitem[" write$
mylabel empty$ 'label 'mylabel if$ write$
"]{" write$
cite$ write$
"}" write$
newline$
""
before.all 'output.state :=
}
```

Can someone please help me with this issue?

[myalphadin.bst file is here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_QQXf8QufsvXpd65z5UNY7cczGBu9mGE/view?usp=sharing)

[complete literature.bib file can be found here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-di6hTk89ggjs58Cxrh7cuxjg2MAdNWW/view?usp=sharing)

I cannot use natbib or others.

Any suggestions or hints will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think bringing `mylabel` in in `FUNCTION {output.bibitem}` is too late. BibTeX needs to be able to figure out the longest label in order to make the indentation work properly.

I think a better place for this is `calc.label`. Make that function read

```
FUNCTION {calc.label}
{ 
  mylabel empty$
    {
      type$ "book" =
      type$ "booklet" =
      type$ "inbook" =
      or or
        'author.editor.key.label
        { type$ "proceedings" =
            'editor.key.organization.label
            { type$ "manual" =
                'author.key.organization.label
                'author.key.label
              if$
            }
          if$
        }
      if$
      duplicate$
      year field.or.null purify$ #-1 #2 substring$
      *
    }
    { mylabel duplicate$ }
  if$
  'label :=
  year field.or.null purify$ #-1 #4 substring$
  *
  sortify 'sort.label :=
}
```

and bring `FUNCTION {output.bibitem}` back to the default

```
FUNCTION {output.bibitem}
{ newline$
  "\bibitem[" write$
  label write$%
  "]{" write$
  cite$ write$
  "}" write$
  newline$
  ""
  before.all 'output.state :=
}
```

You can get the full file with a nicely formatted diff to `alphadin.bst` at https://gist.github.com/moewew/9697e9f14f6a5b15bf1dce6322c31d67.

---

It looks like your `mylabel` is generally just the label `alphadin` would assign anyway with an "-ol" appended. If I understand correctly the idea is to identify online sources like this (something I do not approve of, online sources should be first-class citizens and should not be discriminated against like this). If that is correct, then a nicer, more TeX-y solution would be to let the style add the `-ol` itself. For this you would need a stable way to identify "online sources". Currently the `.bib` file uses `howpublished` and `note` to add URL and access date, but the style supports a `url` field, which would make it easier to identify online sources.

Comment: Thank you so very much!!! I am really really grateful for your help, it works for me. I really invested a lot of time in this ! And yes, you are right about declaring special labels for online resources as not a good practice, but I am not aware how to make the .bib automatically identify online sources and then put a [-ol] on its own. I am not an advanced latex user. Many thanks again!